# How to get object or its index from mouse coordinates?

Tags: 2d, python, pygame

Basically, I have a NumPy array of rectangles that store their colour and position.

I want to be able to compare my mouse position and clicked on the rectangle's position and get the index or the object itself from the array.

Do I have to iterate through every square in the array and compare item's coordinates?

The structure looks like:

`Cube[Face][Horizontal-Line][Square] = np.array([colour, coordinates])`

What's the most efficient way to do it? I'm thinking of using `colliderect()` method, but I don't know how to implement it.

[image: 1]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [it was asked and answered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65552238/3064164). Please ask each question on just one site in the StackExchange network, to keep the best answers gathered in one place for future readers.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to delete this, because it was pointless to ask twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just to use grid system and floor division operator `//`.

Comment: This answer would be better if it showed a sample of the code you used to achieve this.

Comment: I've already asked this in stack overflow site, so it was answered.